# Питон. Не получается сделать replace в названии столбцов по кирилице. С латиницей никаких проблем

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8

Вот такой код проходит без проблем:

`table_import.columns = table_import.columns.str.replace('Unnamed: ', '')`

С таким `table_import.columns = table_import.columns.str.replace('Выполнение', '')` ошибка:

> ```
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in
>     position 0: invalid continuation byte
> ```

В начале скрипта у меня все как положено:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
```

Что же делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: `0xc2` - заглавная русская буква `B` в кодировке Windows-1251. Это первая буква в слове `Выполнение`. Вы пишите на Windows в кодировке Windows-1251. То что в начале файла указан coding не поможет. Поможет пересохранить файл в кодировку UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы код выполнился без ошибок, могу посоветовать следующее:

```
table_import.columns = table_import.columns.str.replace('Выполнение', '').encode('unicode_escape').decode()
```

Как видно - метод эскейпа non-ASCII символов.

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло.